# Stopping ASP.NET CORE 1.0 WebApp on debian

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-applications

I am actually trying to understand .NET Core 1.0 by creating a WebApp on my linux server and I can't start a WebApp using `dotnet run` which is pretty cool, but do you guys know how to start a WebApp? There is no `dotnet stop` or equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft reference [page](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#debian) says that you must `dotnet restore` before start. That restores all dependencies of the application. You can find additional info [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-mac-aspnet.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should `dotnet restore` to restore dependencies.
Then `dotnet run` .
Normally, just press Ctrl + C to break it.

Comment: Yes sure, before starting my WebApp I do a `dotnet restore` and then a `dotnet run`. And I can do the `Ctrl + C` to cancel the process.
One thing is when I leave my putty terminal, the process should be canceled, but he isn't, so when I come back to my terminal again, I have no way to cancel it, how can I do?

Comment: I don't know exactly how to do it. But I think the process should be killed by commands:

`ps -ef | grep dotnet`

`kill -9 [PID]`